# Converting byte[] to SAFEARRAY

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers, pinvoke

I have a problem that I hope someone can help with.  The following code used to compile in VS2012:

```
STDMETHODIMP CGatherStore::GetPathBmp(ULONGLONG sessionID, LONG *pWidth, LONG *pHeight, SAFEARRAY **pData)
{
  m_dbOps.OpenDatabase(m_depository);
  if (m_dbOps.HasPath(sessionID))
  {
    SessionData sd(m_dbOps.GetSessionPath(sessionID));

    *pWidth  = sd.pathHeader.bcWidth;
    *pHeight = sd.pathHeader.bcHeight;

    CComSafeArray<BYTE> bmpArray;
    CComSafeArrayBound  bounds;

    *pData = SafeArrayCreate(VT_UI1, 1, &bounds);
    if (sd.spPathRawData.m_p != NULL)
    {
      bmpArray.Attach(*pData);
      bmpArray.Add(sd.GetPathSize(), reinterpret_cast<BYTE *>(sd.spPathRawData.m_p), true);
      bmpArray.Detach();
    }
  }
  else
  {
    CComSafeArrayBound bounds;

    *pData = SafeArrayCreate(VT_UI1, 1, &bounds);
  }

  return S_OK;
}
```

The exported declaration is as follows:

```
void GetPathBmp(ulong sessionid, out int pWidth, out int pHeight, out Array pData);
```

The function that calls it is as follows:

```
public WriteableBitmap GetBitmapPath(ulong sessionID)
{
  WriteableBitmap bmp = null;

  try
  {
    int    width;
    int    height;
    byte[] data;

    gs.GetPathBmp(sessionID, out width, out height, out data);
    bmp = BitmapFactory.New(width, height);
    bmp.FromByteArray(data);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("GetBitmapPath failed, session ID {0} - {1}", sessionID, e.Message));
  }

  return bmp;
}
```

But when I try to compile it in VS2015 I receive the following error message:

```
error CS1503: Argument 4: cannot convert from 'out byte[]' to 'out System.Array'
```

So how do I convert the variable from byte[] to SAFEARRAY.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that code used to compile?!

Comment: Looks to me like the author of this component changed the IDL for this COM component.  So now the type library importer can (correctly) see that it is an array of bytes.  Usually programmers consider this a solution instead of a problem, albeit that modifying interfaces without changing the [uuid]s is a pretty gross DLL Hell inducer.  Talk to the author or adapt your client code accordingly.

Comment: @HansPassant, I'm genuinely interested - could you explain how "adapt your client code accordingly" is different from my answer (which is showing him how to adapt his client code)?  What am I missing here?

Comment: On top of that, the actual compilation error he's getting is for the C# code, not for the interop ...  that wouldn't be caught until runtime, right?

Comment: @DavidG, no I am not certain that this code used to compile.  The person who wrote it left the company.  I took over what I thought was complete code because we have a working version that I thought was created from the code I was given to start with.  If anyone has a suggestion on what I should do (including using different variable types) I am open to all ideas.

Comment: So you started with an incorrect premise that has everyone confused. Next time be more careful :)

Comment: I just went back through the project history.  The code as I posted it above was created on 1/21/14.  It has been unmodified in the project since then and has been compiled into several releases.  Something did change in VS2015 that caused the code to no longer be valid.  At least I now have a working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the calling function as follows:

```
public WriteableBitmap GetBitmapPath(ulong sessionID)
{
  WriteableBitmap bmp = null;
  try
  {
    int          width;
    int          height;
    System.Array sa;

    gs.GetPathBmp(sessionID, out width, out height, out sa);
    bmp = BitmapFactory.New(width, height);

    byte[] data = new byte[sa.Length];
    sa.CopyTo(data, 0);
    bmp.FromByteArray(data);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("GetBitmapPath failed, session ID {0} - {1}", sessionID, e.Message));
  }
  return bmp;
}
```

It seems to work.  Thanks for everyone's help.